# WPF .NET Core - how to find source of dependency property changed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I need to run code on `ListViewItem` mouse over event. I tried several solutions which none worked for me.

I came up with this:

```
        private void ProcessListItems()
        {
            foreach (var item in settings.items)
            {
                var i = lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
                if (i == null)
                    continue;

                BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ItemMouseOverProperty, new Binding
                {
                    Path = new PropertyPath(ListViewItem.IsMouseOverProperty),
                    Source = i 
                });
            }
        }

        public bool ItemMouseOver
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ItemMouseOverProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemMouseOverProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemMouseOverProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemMouseOver", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnItemMouseOverChanged));

        static void OnItemMouseOverChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Once all items are added to the listview I bind each item `ItemMouseOverProperty` to my own dep prop `ItemMouseOverProperty`.

Now I need to find which `ListViewItem` triggered it..

**In short: I bind one dep property to another. I want to find out which `source` object raised the `changed` event.**

Comment: That's a bad question. The context is absolutely not clear. Stop posting unrelated code snippets or snippets without context, please. They are totally meaningless for people that don't know your project. That's a very bad and very annoying habbit here. How can we know the context in which you need the solution? The solution most often depends on such details.

Comment: @BionicCode Why do you answer then? Vote to close and proceed.

Comment: @Clemens You are absolutely right. I downvoted the question to express my discontent.

Comment: if **you** dont see the context it doesnt mean its not there

Comment: If you be honest, then you would admit that you didn't show much code. I'm not the only one here that finds that your question lacks information. Don't know your skill level, but you could undertsand that in order to fix design related code issues you always need the context of the code, not only the problem it tries to solve. No problem, you could have easily provided more information to improve this question to make helping you easier. But instead you fight back. I don't want to attack you, but that's just stubborn: it doesn't help anybody to help you and therefore it doesn't help you.

Comment: Let's forget about it. Next time we will get along better.

Comment: ok. but just for the record. I did say - "need to run code on ListViewItem mouse over event".. simple as that.. there is nothing more in it...

Comment: Me as the person who needs to solve your problem needs to know where your code is located and executed. That's why my last comment reads *"...always need the context of the code, not only the problem it tries to solve"*. It matters. What you said *"need to run code on ListViewItem mouse over event"* describes the problem without any context. "I'm extending a ListView and ..." provides *some* context. To see this context as code is even better as implementation details can matter too. *"simple as that.. there is nothing more in it"*.

Comment: When you ask me if I know how to fix your car and I say "yes, but bring your torque wrench", then why would say "nah, this is irrelevant"  although you don't undestand the problem nor did you know the solution? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of your code is not clear. Are you extending ListView or is this code-behind?

Generally, you can attach event handlers to the `ListViewItem.MouseEnter` event by adding a `EventSetter` to the style:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseEnter" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>

private void ListViewItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var mouseOverItem = sender as ListViewItem;
}
```

Depending on your exact context, you can also define triggers and trigger on `ListBoxItem.IsMouseOver`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. re: context - it is irrelevant. I bind one dep property to another. I want to find out which **source** object raised the `changed` event. what is it unclear about it?

Comment: "you can also trigger on ListBoxItem.IsMouseOver" - the only way I know is to use EventTrigger and they are not designed to run code only certain XAML actions. I tried command binding and failed.

Comment: *"what is it unclear about it?"* I told you what's unclear. What you are doing is not possible - totally wrong approach. And in order to provide you the proper solution man needs more context. It's quite bold of you you call the request of the person you asked for help irrelevant. I was not complaining just to complain. I wanted to help and realized that in order to provide you the best solution there is some crucial information missing. It feels like you approach me very arrogant telling me my request for information is irrelevant. It's arrogant or ignorant.

Comment: *"the only way I know is to use EventTrigger"*. It's not the only way.